# How to pass text/plain content in axios POST request in nodejs

Tags: node.js, axios

I want to pass body parameters as shown in screen shot [image: here] (**in text/plain format**)

I am using axios in my nodejs/express project . My reqeust format is as shown below:

```
var config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Length': 0,
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    }
};



const testInput = (req, res) => {
    axios.post('https://api.sandbox.xyz.com/v1/order/new', { firstName: 'Marlon' }, config)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log('saved successfully')
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
};
```

For this how can I pass the body parameters appropriately?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It looks fine to me

Comment: I want to pass `{
    "request": "/v1/order/new",
    "nonce": 123457,

    "client_order_id": "20150102-4738721",
    "symbol": "btcusd",
    "amount": "34.12",
    "price": "622.13",
    "side": "buy",
    "type": "exchange limit"
}` as body parameter, how would I do that?

Comment: Instead of `{ firstName: '...' }` you use that object you just posted?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Length': 0,
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    },
   responseType: 'text'
};
```

1. `responseType` indicates the type of data that the server will
   respond with
2. options are arraybuffer , blob , document, json , text, stream