# Node Express API Treating File As JSON

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, vuetify.js

I am developing an app that has a Node/Express API server and VueJS/Vuetify client. In my client I am using v-file-input to prompt user for file. On click of "Import" button I'm calling a Vue method which makes an API post to my server. In my server I've added "express-fileupload" as a dependency, require and use it in my server's app.js to handle file uploads. In my route I reference req.files, but am getting an error stating "Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0" (the file content has a letter "P" as the first character). It appears that even though I reference req.files (not req.body), the server is trying to interpret JSON rather than a file input. I'm unclear how to correct this.

Client VUE:

```
  <div>
    <h1 class="page-heading">Jobs Import</h1>
    <v-card elevation="5" width="1000" class="mx-auto mt-5">
      <v-card-title>
        Import Jobs
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-subtitle>
          This import accepts a file saved from Kiwiplan. Reference <b>Kiwiplan Job Run List Save</b> instructions for details on how to create the import file.
      </v-card-subtitle>
      <v-card-text>
          <v-form>
            <v-container>
                <v-row>
                    <v-file-input v-model="chosenFile" accept=".txt" label="Import file" prepend-icon="mdi-file-upload-outline"></v-file-input>
                </v-row>
            </v-container>
          </v-form>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn type="submit" color="info" @click="importFile">Import</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
      <v-snackbar v-model="snackbar">
          {{ snackbarText }}
            <template v-slot:action="{ attrs }">
                <v-btn color="pink" text v-bind="attrs" @click="snackbar = false">
                    Close
                </v-btn>
            </template>
      </v-snackbar>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import dataService from "../services/dataService.js";
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            chosenFile: null,
            snackbar: false,
            snackbarText: ""
        }
    },
    methods: {
        importFile() {
            dataService
                .importJobs(this.chosenFile)
                .then ((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Client dataService:

```
const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8085',
    withCredentials: false,
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
});

export default {

    // Jobs API Calls

    getJobs() {
        return apiClient.get('/job/pending')
    },

    postJob(data) {
        return apiClient.post('/job', data)
    },

    patchJob(data) {
        return apiClient.patch('/job/' + data._id, data)
    },

    deleteJob(id) {
        return apiClient.delete('/job/' + id)
    },

    importJobs(data) {
        return apiClient.post('/job/import', data);
    },

    // Settings API Calls

    getSettings() {
        return apiClient.get('/settings')
    },

    postSettings(data) {
        return apiClient.post('/settings', data)
    }
}
```

Server Route (/import post):

```
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');
const fixy = require('fixy');
const RollPlanJobs = require('../models/rollPlanJobsModel');

// Retrieve All Roll Plan Jobs
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const jobs = await RollPlanJobs.find();
        res.json(jobs);
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err });
    }
});

// Retrieve Unsubmitted Roll Plan Jobs
router.get('/pending', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const jobs = await RollPlanJobs.find({ rollPlan_id: '' });
        res.json(jobs);
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err });
    }
});

// Submit Single Roll Plan Job
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const rollPlanJob = new RollPlanJobs({
        rollPlan_id: req.body.rollPlan_id,
        outputRollId: req.body.outputRollId,
        piSequence: req.body.piSequence,
        jobId: req.body.jobId,
        customerName: req.body.customerName,
        partNumber: req.body.partNumber,
        jobSourceItemId: req.body.jobSourceItemId,
        jobName: req.body.customerName + " / " + req.body.partNumber,
        itemWidth: req.body.itemWidth,
        jobPaperWidth: calcPaperWidth(Number(req.body.itemWidth)),
        itemLength: req.body.itemLength,
        quantity: req.body.quantity,
        jobLength: calcJobLength(Number(req.body.quantity), Number(req.body.itemLength)),
        boardGrade: req.body.boardGrade,
        qualityMode: req.body.qualityMode,
        opv: req.body.opv,
        jobSpec: req.body.jobSpec,
        jobTarget: req.body.jobTarget,
        jobPrintFile: req.body.jobPrintFile,
    });
    try {
        const savedRollPlan = await rollPlanJob.save();
        res.json(savedRollPlan);
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err });
    }
});

// Update Roll Plan Job
router.patch('/:jobId', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const updatedJob = await RollPlanJobs.updateOne({ _id: req.params.jobId }, { $set: {
            rollPlan_id: req.body.rollPlan_id,
            outputRollId: req.body.outputRollId,
            piSequence: req.body.piSequence,
            jobId: req.body.jobId,
            customerName: req.body.customerName,
            partNumber: req.body.partNumber,
            jobSourceItemId: req.body.jobSourceItemId,
            jobName: req.body.customerName + " / " + req.body.partNumber,
            itemWidth: req.body.itemWidth,
            jobPaperWidth: calcPaperWidth(Number(req.body.itemWidth)),
            itemLength: req.body.itemLength,
            quantity: req.body.quantity,
            jobLength: calcJobLength(Number(req.body.quantity), Number(req.body.itemLength)),
            boardGrade: req.body.boardGrade,
            qualityMode: req.body.qualityMode,
            opv: req.body.opv,
            jobSpec: req.body.jobSpec,
            jobTarget: req.body.jobTarget,
            jobPrintFile: req.body.jobPrintFile,
        }});
        res.json(updatedJob);
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err });
    }
});

// Delete Specific Roll Plan Job
router.delete('/:jobId', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const deletedJob = await RollPlanJobs.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.jobId });
        res.json(deletedJob);
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err });
    }
});

// Import Roll Plan Jobs
router.post('/import', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const buffer = fs.readFileSync(req.files.chosenFile);
        const fileContent = buffer.toString();
        const fileContentFinal = fileContent.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '\n');
        const txt2json = fixy.parse({
            map:
            [
                {
                    name: "code",
                    width: 2,
                    start: 1,
                    type: "string"
                },
                {
                    name: "lineNum",
                    width: 3,
                    start: 3,
                    type: "string"
                },
                {
                    name: "jobId",
                    width: 11,
                    start: 6,
                    type: "string"
                },
                {
                    name: "customer",
                    width: 7,
                    start: 17,
                    type: "string"
                }
            ],
            options:
            {
                fullwidth: 23,
                skiplines: null,
                format: json
            }
        }, fileContentFinal);
        res.send(txt2json);
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err });
    }
});

function calcJobLength(qty, length) {
    return Math.round((qty * length) / 12);
}

function calcPaperWidth(width) {
    if (width < 24) {
        return "24";
    }
    else if (width > 24 && width < 27) {
        return "27";
    }
    else if (width > 27 && width < 30) {
        return "30";
    }
    else if (width > 30 && width < 33) {
        return "33";
    }
    else if (width > 33 && width < 36) {
        return "36";
    }
    else if (width > 36 && width < 39) {
        return "39";
    }
    else {
        return "42";
    }
}

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You didn't show dataService.

Comment: Client dataService code added to post for reference.

Comment: You can see what's sent in devtools and with which headers. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318283/how-to-pass-text-plain-content-in-axios-post-request-in-nodejs